# Construct a random variable uniformly distributed around a value from another uniform distribution

Tags: random-variable, uniform-distribution

Consider a continuous random variable $H$, uniformly distributed over range $[1,2]$, i.e. $H\sim U(1,2)$. Someone draws $h^*$ from $H$. Consider now a value $h'=h^{*\gamma}c\;(\gamma<1)$ , where $c$ is a constant bounded within $[1,2]$.

My question is "is it possible to construct a random variable $H'$ (through any transformation from $H$, i.e. $H'=g(H)$) that satisfies the following conditions?":

1. $E[H']=h'$, that is mean of $H'$ is $h'$
2. $H'$ is also bounded within range $[1,2]$ or any subrange within $[1,2]$

I have tried $H'=H^\gamma c^\theta$ but since this is unconditional on $h'$ or $h^*$, I was unable to get the mean to be $h'=h^{*\gamma}c$.

---

***edit:**

Let the level of human capital of the **parent generation** be $H$ which is uniformly distributed between $1$ and $2$, i.e. $H\sim U(1,2)$. Let $h^*$ (or $h$ if you so prefer) denote the human capital of an individual from the parent's generation (not a fixed value). Consider now the level of human capital of the **child generation**, $H'$. Given $h^*$ and $H$, I want to find a function $g(H)$ that could transform $H$ into $H'$ that satisfies the following two conditions.

1. $E[H']=h^{*\gamma}c$
2. $H'$ is also bounded within range $[1,2]$ or any subrange within $[1,2]$

What I have in mind is that "for a parent with a given level of human capital, his/her child's level of human capital is a random variable satisfying mentioned conditions." Since $h^*$ is not a fixed value, for any $h^*$ within the range $[1,2]$, a different $H'$ is constructed (since the mean will be different each time) I hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Assuming $\gamma\gt 0$ and $g$ is allowed to depend on $\gamma$ and $c,$ the answer is (often) yes; otherwise not. In the former case there are infinitely many, highly varied solutions.  Please, then, explain your objective: give us some clues as to why you want to do this so we can narrow the possibilities.

Comment: I also find the question very unclear bewteen the use of $H$ and $h$. Is $h$ or $h^*$ a fixed value?

Comment: @whuber Yes there is no restriction on $g$. Do you reckon I should give it a bit of contextual information? I can edit the post if it helps.

Comment: @Xi'an $h^*$ is a value (not fixed) drawn from $H$, that is any value within the range $[1,2]$. I did some transformations on both $H$, the random variable, and $h^*$, the value. The former will give me a new random variable $H'$, whereas the latter gives me another value $h'$. Hope that clears up the confusion.

Comment: We need that contextual information.

Comment: @whuber I have made some edits. Please let me know if further clarifications are needed.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately "parent generation" and "child generation" do not add any information to your post.  What we need is some hints about how $H^\prime$ and $H$ are likely to be related: that would change your question from a pure math problem (with a wide range of answers) to a statistical problem (with, perhaps, a unique correct answer).